# Setting Up Python Script tool ( ESRI arcpy ) to download files from table

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, parameters

It's been years since I have worked with ArcPy and I'm having trouble setting up the parameters in my script tool.

What I'm trying to do:

I have a layer file (.lyr) that is a state wide index grid of available elevation model tiles.  The layer's attribute table has a field "URL" that contains the download link.  In my map document, I want to be able to make a selection of records in the layer and download the elevation model image tiles in my selected project area.

Here's the layer file. And the data table at the bottom:

[image]

What works:

I can run the script tool successfully but it's downloading all 15,000 files in the table not just my selected records.

this is the .py behind my script tool:

`

```
import urllib

import os

import arcpy

#where am I saving the download?
path = (str(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)))
os.chdir(path)


#path to my index layer...stil unsure how to get this as a dropdown menu item in my tool
fc= r"C:\Users\Z\Desktop\LiDAR_Index.lyr"
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)

for row in cursor:
    field ="URL"
    link =(row.getValue(field))
    head, tail = os.path.split(str(link))
    print "Downloading: "+ tail
    download=urllib.urlretrieve((str(link)), tail)
```

`

I'm lost as to how to only make this act on the selected records and not the whole feature class or shapefile.

Current UI on left and tool properties on right:

[image]

Comment: What version of ArcGIS?

Comment: Are you selecting these features in a layer in ArcMap, and then only want to output those selected features?

Comment: v 10.4
correct...I want to select a bunch of records, lets say a full city's coverage of DEM tiles, and run the tool to save the files all in one shot rather than individually downloading 15-20 individually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I see the problem.  If you're selecting features in your layer in ArcMap and then running this script, the script isn't looking at the layer, but rather at a layer file `.lyr` stored elsewhere which doesn't have a selection.  You need to tell your script to use your ArcMap layer, or to select the matching features in the layer file.

If you add the `mxd` line and change the `fc` line as follows, it should read your layer from within ArcMap.

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
fc = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Lidar Index")[0]
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
```

It's also possible to make that a dropdown in your script tool.  Change the DATA TYPE setting from `String` to `Layer` for your first parameter, and it should list all the layers in your current MXD.  You could then pass this as a parameter to your script rather than specifying the name of the Layer in the List Layers.

Comment: Midavalo was right on money. Thanks! 
needed to specify the current mxd 

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") 
fc = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Lidar Index")[0] 

And since this is a the same .lyr that my whole department uses, I think I'm OK hard coding the layer name rather than dealing with the drop-down menu.  That also means that I only need one parameter in the tool.